# Android: Adding a Second Action Bar to the footer of the activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, footer

How would I go about setting up a second action bar which would be stationed at the footer of the screen. Ill also have a scrollable list view on the page and what I would like is that when I scroll through this table, the action bar at the bottom will remain stationary and visible at all times. Thanks in advance! Will

Comment: You mean you wan to split actionbar? @Will

Comment: You can use toolbar and actionbar both for this .

Comment: Use relative layout and set any view property like this : android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and set listview property android:layout_above the your bottom view

Comment: Yeh essentially a split action bar but I would like to decide what would be on each and be able to customize the look @Pooja

Comment: Nice suggestion @sanat shukla, ill give it a go!